# prove that this map is continuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let G be ${\bf R}$,with addition as the group operation and with the topology for which the open sets are those that either are empty or have a countable complement.

We want to show that the map [($x_0$,y) $\longmapsto$ $x_0$+y]:{$x_0$} $\times$ R $\longrightarrow$ R is continuous.

first,suppose that $x_0$ $\in$ G is fixed.Let U be open in R.Then,U:=R-$(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ for some countable collection $(x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $\subset$ R.The complete preimage of U is {($x_0$,y):$x_0$+y $\in$ U}={($x_0$,y):y-$x_0$ $\neq$ $x_n$,n $\in$ N}={$x_0$} $\times$ (U-$(x_n-x_0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$).
This is a relatively open subset of { $x_0$} $\times$ R. hence the map [($x_0$,y) $\longmapsto$ $x_0$+y]:{$x_0$} $\times$ R $\longrightarrow$ R is continuous.

Q1:I don't know how he get {$x_0$} $\times$ (U-$(x_n-x_0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$) from {($x_0$,y):$x_0$+y $\in$ U}.

Q2: why {$x_0$} $\times$ (U-$(x_n-x_0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$) is a  relatively open subset of {$x_0$} $\times$ R.

Comment: I think you need to check very carefully your typing as there are many thing that are unclear: what is U-x_n-$(x_0)_{n=1}^\infty$ , for example?

Comment: i edited it .I think it is clear now .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really don't understand what you wrote, but I can think of the following: take an open $\;U\subset\Bbb R\;$ , so if we denote your map as $\;f: \{x_0\}\times\Bbb R\to\Bbb R\;$ , then$${}$$

$$\Bbb R\setminus U=\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\implies f^{-1}(U)=\left\{(x_0,y)\in\{x_0\}\times\Bbb R\;;\;\;x_0+y\neq x_n\right\}=$$$${}$$

$$=\left\{\,(x_0,\,y)\in\{x_0\}\times\Bbb R\;;\;\;y\neq x_n-x_0\,\right\} =\{x_0\}\times\left(\Bbb R\setminus\{x_0-x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\right)$$$${}$$

which proves $\;f^{-1}(U)\;$ is open in the (product) topological space $\;\{x_0\}\times\Bbb R\;$ and thus $\;f\;$ is continuous.

Comment: Also note that while addition is continuous for a fixed operand (it's a bijection, and all bijections are continuous on the reals with  the co-countable topology; this also holds for inversion e.g.) it's not continuous on the whole product, as it's a $T_1$ but not $T_2$ topology. This cannot happen for a topological group.

Comment: @Joanpemo But i see that $f^{-1}$(U)=[{$x_0$} $\times$ (R \ $(x_n-x_0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$)]. and  how 
 is this set open in ${x_0}$ $\times$ R.

Comment: @aya_haitham It isn't given, but I assume the topology on $\;\{x_0\}\times\Bbb R\;$ is the product topology: something's open there iff it is of the form $\;A\times B\;$ , with $\;A\;$ open in $\;\{x_0\}\;$ (there aren't many options here), and $\;B\;$ open in $\;\Bbb R\;$ with the countable complement topology.

Comment: yes,i see.But you write that f^{-1}(U)=({$x_0$} $\times$ R) \ [{$x_0$} $\times$  (R \ $(x_n-x_0)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ )]

Comment: @aya_haitham Oh, I see. That was a typo. Thank you, corrected.